# Empty file returned with Ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, download

I have a JSON string I pass through an Ajax call when triggering a button.
The first thing I would like to be able to do and understand would be to pass the variable back in a generated file without saving it to server.

The strange thing that happens here is that the variable value is retrieved by the callback function and is displayed by the alert(data) call,
while the POST variable is recognised as empty and the JS script brings me to a blank process-data.php page.

When taking off the empty() condition I still get the variable displayed properly
but instead of having a blank page I get a 0 octet file to download.

Could this be a server problem, for info I'm running MAMP?

thanks for your answers.

Here is the HTML code

```
<button onclick="aCall()" button type="submit" formmethod="post"> DL "x" value as text </button>
```

Ajax code:

```
function aCall(){
    $.ajax({
         url: 'process-data.php',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {'value': [{x:250,y:300}]}, //that's an example
         success: function(data){
               alert(data);
               window.location = 'process-data.php';
          }
    });
}
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
<?php
   if (!empty($_POST['value'])) //I get a blank page with that condition on and a file if off.
   {
       $filename = 'test.txt';

       header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
       header("Content-Length: ". filesize("$filename").";");
       header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
       header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream; "); 
       header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
       header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
       header('Expires: 0');
       header('Pragma: public');

       echo $_POST['value'][0]['x'];
       exit;

    }
?>
```

in short here is what I get.

```
HTML -> AJAX -> PHP -> echo myValue
                             |
                             |
       empty file <----------|
       or Blank page         |
                             |
       popup                 |
       showing the <---------'
       variable's 
       value
```

Comment: "The strange thing that happens ..." Why talk about the POST variable *after* the callback? Which part of what happens is strange?

Comment: I've edited  my post. What happens is can retrieve the value I want via the the callback, but my file is empty.

Comment: Are you sure you can `echo` like that in place of `readfile()`? You might also like to check the `Content-Length:` header.

Comment: Well it works if I put a normal string like  echo "exString" it returns me a file with that string inside it. Same thing if I put echo "exString".myValue."otherString", I would get "exStringotherString" in my file and "exString250otherString" in my popup.

Comment: echo $_POST['value'] returns me my json string in popup an "NULL" on the page

Comment: Then maybe it's to do with `250` being a number, not a string?

Comment: i've tried with almost everything, I've casted the variable (string) anymore ideas what it could be?

Comment: Charset issue? (though don't ask me how or why)

Comment: Nop :( that's not changing anything...

Comment: What happens if you code `data: {'value': "250"},` in javascript and echo `$_POST('value')` in PHP?

Comment: same thing. Really weird...

Comment: Client-side, try commenting out the success handler.

Comment: I get nothing as the "window.location = 'process-data.php';" is disabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify like this, no need of `json_decode`

From

```
if (!empty(json_decode($_POST['value'])))
```

To

```
if(isset($_POST['value']) && !empty($_POST['value']))
```

and

From

```
echo $json[0]->x;
```

to

```
echo $_POST['value'][0]['x'];
```

Comment: I've already tried without the JSON but trying to get the value directly through the $_POST variable gives me strange results. You might have raised an interesting point, I'll test and get back to you. thanks

Comment: Finally what happens is this does'nt work for one reason is that my Post variable is recognised as String so that gives me the first bracket $_POST['value'][0]    gives  "["   and  $_POST['value'][3]    gives  "x". Any clues how to solve this?  Thx